# Matlab code for Lyapunov

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

How can I plot a Lyapunov curve for this system
\begin{cases}
  \frac{d\phi}{dx}=Z\\
\frac{dZ}{dx}=\frac{1}{B}(U\phi-\frac{A}{2}\phi^2)+\frac{f\cos\omega x}{B}
\end{cases}
with
 $$A=1, B=0.43, U=0.9, f=0.05, \omega= 0.5$$

Comment: Please define "Lyapunov curve".

Comment: Note also that the system is not autonomous and you should be careful defining what exactly you want to plot.